# How to implement pgAgent Jobs in PostgreSQL 15?

Tags: postgresql, jobs, postgresql-12, pgagent, postgresql-15

What do I have to do so that PostgreSQL 15 using pgAdmin shows me the "pgAgent Jobs" section? It is not enough to create the extension and update, unlike PostgreSQL 12.

PostgreSQL 12
[image]

PostgreSQL 15
[image]